# Angular empty router link

Tags: angular

In angular 11 I'm dynamically rendering a navigation component. So have code like this:

```
<li [routerLinkActive]="active">
    <a [routerLink]="navItem.route">navItem.linkText</a>
</li>
```

This is fine except where I've a nav section that isn't actually a route but rather triggers subitems to open. I still want the routerLinkActive to correctly apply the class but I don't want it to navigate anywhere.

The route value is empty but this doesn't work, so I've tried setting it to an empty array like this:

```
<li [routerLinkActive]="active">
    <a [routerLink]="navItem.route ? navItem.route: []">navItem.linkText</a>
</li>
```

But the empty array is interpreted as linking to my homepage so on initial render the homepage link is highlighted but so are any sub items that have empty routes.

Is there a way in angular to dynamically create a navigation like I'm doing, have the routerlinkactive directive correctly apply the class but for the link to not actually navigate anywhere?

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```html
<li [routerLinkActive]="active">
    <a [routerLink]="navItem.route ? navItem.route: undefined">navItem.linkText</a>
</li>
```

Comment: undefined did work for me weird. I used it like this thought `[routerLink]="false ? 'inspection' : undefined"` I don't know what you have in navItem

Comment: At true, I get to `localhost:4200/inspection` and at false, nothing happen.

Comment: if navItem.route is a string, navItem.route is always true then

Comment: Does the routerLinkActive apply for you when the routerLink is undefined?

Comment: I don't use `routerLinkActive` like you do, I use it directly on the `<a></a>` element. But if the route dosen't match the `routerLink`, it will not active.

Comment: But say I'm at /inspection, it will be active yes.

Comment: Alright I just tried and when undefined, it stays active all the time...

Comment: I need it to be active for both - if the link is a valid link the active class should be applied. If the link isn't actually a link I still need the active class applied. I can't get it to work no matter what I've tried

Comment: Even with `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"` it does not fix the problem.

Comment: The only way I see you could make it work, is if you have `/route/navItem.route`.

Comment: That way active with options `exact:false` route will be active too.

Comment: But I don't see how you can use that with your case, but that's the only way I know how to get double active link

Comment: kind of like this if you didnt understood: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8397